# change time format for ps time in unix

Tags: linux, unix, ps

I am trying to get back the time in the format **hh:mm** without the seconds,
running this:

```
 ps -p $pid -o time=
```

gets back (*for example*) `00:03:19` but I want just (*for example*) `00:03`

I have tried looking at the manual and searched on the net, couldn't find anything that i can understand. Can someone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ps` itself doesn't offer to configure the time format. However, you can pipe to `cut`:

```
ps -p $pid -o time= | cut -d: -f1,2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, this helps!!